# "Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type" in blockproc(I_STRUCT.coef_arrays{1},[8 8],fun);

Tags: matlab, imread

After imread into a variable and sending it to the function, it returns an error "Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type."

Not sure why, it seemed to work with jpg, but with pgm it fails despite using same function

```
stego = imread('1.pgm');
quality_factor = 75;

fun = @(x)x.data .*stego.quant_tables{1};
I_spatial = blockproc(stego.coef_arrays{1},[8 8],fun)
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible code sample.

Comment: There is not nearly enough context to know what you did or what the error message means in your case. Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Added minimal reproducible example

Comment: After `imread()`, `stego` is a plain numeric array. You can only use dot indexing (`stego.something`) on a struct or a class object. I don't think this would have worked with a JPEG either.

Comment: Googling, I found `jpeg_read`, which you might have been using to load the quantization tables of a JPEG file (instead of `imread`, which only returns the uncompressed pixel data). Obviously, PGM files do not use JPEG encryption, and don't have quantization tables.

Comment: Thank you, indeed, I assumed that they were equal functions for different formats. My bad. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Bad attempt at using pmg instead of jpg, assumed that jpeg_read was equal to imgread. Instead of sending a struct to the function sent array.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).